# how to make 6 range input in form

Tags: javascript, forms, input, range

hello i want to enable 6 range input but when i do it 
one only work and 5 not working
lets try

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");

var output = document.getElementById("demo");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
                        <input name="act" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p> Activities: <span id="demo"></span>%</p>




                                         <input name="his" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="price">
  <p>History: <span id="result"></span>%</p>



                                         <input name="nig" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange2">
  <p>Nightlife: <span id="demo2"></span>%</p>


   <input name="beat" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange3">
  <p>Beaches: <span id="demo3"></span>%</p>
  
  
     <input name="natu" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange4">
  <p>Nature: <span id="demo4"></span>%</p>
  
     <input name="shop" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange5">
  <p>Shopping: <span id="demo5"></span>%</p>
```

i want to make all working with values 
now how i can make it working every input with his value

Comment: `document.getElementById("myRange")` only grabs a reference to the first slider (the one with the id="myRange"). You will have to do the same thing for the other sliders. `document.getElementById("myRange2")` etc

Comment: i do it but not working u can try and give me run code snippet to see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only added an event handler for one of the inputs, so the other ones will not work. You can get all of the inputs with a query selector (all your inputs have a class of `slider` so we can use `document.querySelector('input.slider')`) and use a `for` loop to iterate through them and get the `span` to display the percentage with `nextElementSibling`.

```html
                        <input name="act" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p> Activities: <span id="demo" class="slider"></span>%</p>




                                         <input name="his" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="price">
  <p>History: <span id="result" class="slider"></span>%</p>



                                         <input name="nig" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange2">
  <p>Nightlife: <span id="demo2" class="slider"></span>%</p>


   <input name="beat" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange3">
  <p>Beaches: <span id="demo3" class="slider"></span>%</p>
  
  
     <input name="natu" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange4">
  <p>Nature: <span id="demo4" class="slider"></span>%</p>
  
     <input name="shop" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange5">
  <p>Shopping: <span id="demo5" class="slider"></span>%</p>
  <script>
 var sliders = document.querySelectorAll("input.slider");



for(let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++){
var slider = sliders[i];
slider.nextElementSibling.querySelector('span.slider').innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
   this.nextElementSibling.querySelector('span.slider').innerHTML = this.value;
  }
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the handle function for the other range sliders...
Each range slider must have its own "oninput" function, e.g. for slider history:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");

var output = document.getElementById("demo");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

// You miss implementing the code for the 5 other ranges
// You must implement the "oninput" for each range slider
var slider2 = document.getElementById("price");

var output2 = document.getElementById("result");

output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
                        <input name="act" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p> Activities: <span id="demo"></span>%</p>




                                         <input name="his" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="price">
  <p>History: <span id="result"></span>%</p>



                                         <input name="nig" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange2">
  <p>Nightlife: <span id="demo2"></span>%</p>


   <input name="beat" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange3">
  <p>Beaches: <span id="demo3"></span>%</p>
  
  
     <input name="natu" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange4">
  <p>Nature: <span id="demo4"></span>%</p>
  
     <input name="shop" style="    width: 70%;
    float: right;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange5">
  <p>Shopping: <span id="demo5"></span>%</p>
```